# react-native-contacts unable to add contact

Tags: react-native

I am using [react-native-contacts](https://github.com/rt2zz/react-native-contacts) for adding contacts. On click of a button I am executing the below code to add the contacts. But I am unable to add it the console warn msg prints out. Am I doing anything wrong?

```js
const newPerson = {
      emailAddresses: [{
        label: 'work',
        email: 'sample@example.com'
      }],
      givenName: 'Some Name',
      phoneNumbers: [{
        label: 'mobile',
        number: '9999999999'
      }],
    };
    Contacts.addContact(newPerson, (err) => {
      console.warn('unable to add');
    });
```